# Iframe form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, submit, form-submit

I have web-site, and form inside.

But form is inside iframe. Iframe was added dynamicaly after clicking on button.

I need catch submit event on this form. How can i do this?

I tryed with this code:

```
$('#frameContent').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    $(this).find('iframe').load(function(){
        console.log('frame loaded');
        $('form').submit(function(){
            console.log('test');
        });
    });
});
```

I see only frame loaded message. I've try to change form selector but this didn't work too. Also i need catch submiting and send ajax request before this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you control the content of the iframe? And is it on the same domain?

Comment: No( Its 3rd party site.

Comment: I'm fairly confident what you want isn't possible then. If it was it would be a massive security hole - imagine, you could put gmail in an iframe and listen to someone typing in their password. You should only be able to access sensitive content inside iframe that are from your same domain.

Comment: What about create different form, and take data from frame. I mean take url and hidden inputs.

Comment: I have access to GTM in iframe. Thats can work?